# Entity Framework 6 - refresh code first classes and dbcontext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm new to EF, and so far what I preffer using is Code First on an existing database (I believe that db should be designed and maintained by a DBA and that classes should be kept simple and no encapsulated in the edmx file).

So what I've done is reverse engineer a database using Entity Framework Power Tools. I got my classes and dbcontext just fine.

Now my database was changed and I want to refresh my code (classes and dbcontext) - which as I see is an advantage of using edmx files - but I use code first.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: @YuliamChandra - how can it be done?

Comment: Just do the same when you reverse engineer the database, but delete the context class and related connection string key first.